# effect of BufferSize

Tags: c#, buffer, streamwriter

I have a program that uses multithreading (lots of thread) and needs to log data from each thread. It outputs a lot of really small data samples but does that very fast. My data interest is to log all samples in a continuous way.

So i need to log only a few numbers that update with high frequency. 
I would like to append the data to a single file (multiple threads to one file).

What wonders me, if i make use of streamwriter ea

```
const int BufferSize = 65536;  // 64 Kilobytes
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("filename", true, Encoding.UTF8, BufferSize);
```

Whats the effect of Buffersize?
Will no data be written until the buffer is full or till stream writter is flushed to disk? (or flushed by making use of a using construction (ending using statement flushes as well).  As for program design i could put stream writer method inside each thread, or create a single writer on program startup (so that threads only perform the append write).

To me fast logging is important, and all should be written to disk as i may not loose samples. I must be assured it all-ways gets written and not queued because the buffer isnt full yet. I also need to provide this data in a continuous way not until some button is hit. (cannot store it in memory)

Comment: Your requirements state that you *don't* want to buffer.  So of course the  buffer size does not matter at all.  Set AutoFlush = true and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`AutoFlush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx) property to make it flush the buffer to the Stream after every call to `StreamWriter.Write()`

If you're going to make a few calls to `StreamWriter.Write()` in quick succession, you can call [`Flush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) instead to force it to flush the buffer to the file.

Comment: so many writes continously would e autoflush then, thanks i didnt knew that it had such an option